# Having Issue creating a custom layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, layout

I have written the following code in Android Studio in order to generate a custom layout with a text and an image. The problem I'm dealing with is that it does not show me the second layout when I click on the button. What is wrong with this code?

```
package com.example.test_practice_itemselection;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
LayoutInflater layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    layout = getLayoutInflater();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            View customLayout = layout.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
            builder.setTitle("This is a custom layout").setView(customLayout)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

As a matter of fact, when I click on the button in the `main_activity`, the application will be terminated.

Comment: "As a matter of fact, when I click on the button in the main_activity, the application will be terminated." - Post your error / stacktrace. Based on your code, you're never initializing the dialog builder, so it would be null and crash.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. The custom layout activity just cannot be initialized. When I click on the button, the custom layout activity will be terminated

Comment: If your application is terminating, that would indicate an error. Have you looked at LogCat?